# jquery sortable can not work？

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Could anyone can tell me how to add effect to all divs？

jQuery：

```
data = $("#sortable_list1").sortable("serialize");

update:function()
        {    

            $.ajax({
                data:serial,
                url:"list.php",
                type:"post",
                success:function(data){
                $("#serverResponse").html(data);
                }
            });             
        }
```

Html：

I have 2 divs which id is sortable_list1

item1
item2



item1
item2

but it only first sortable_list1 can be serialize.how to sorable second or more? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two elements with same id. Id is an attribute that identifies the element on a page, so instead of having two divs with same id i'd suggest you adding same class to them and then doing `$('div.yourGivenClass').sortable...`

Comment: Can you edfit you question and add the code that you modified, in response, to Eimantas' answer?